# DataReader to Linq'd query of Dictionary(String, Object)

Tags: vb.net, linq, datareader

Why doesn't the compiler like this:

```
        Dim AdDr As SqlDataReader = Addcommand.ExecuteReader()
        Dim query = From row In AdDr.Cast(Of Data.Common.DbDataRecord)() _
                    Select New With { _
                        .Items = New Dictionary(Of String, Object)( _
                            (From ii In Enumerable.Range(0, row.FieldCount) _
                             Select New DictionaryEntry(key:=row.GetName(ii), value:=row.GetValue(ii)))) _
                        }
        Dim rslt = query.ToList()
```

The first part works just fine, if all I want is a query of the rows. However, what I really want is a query that provides rows that are Dictionary(of String, Object) with the key being the FieldName and the value being the DataItem.

Answer (score 1):

Currently an `IEnumerable` is being passed to the constructor of `Dictionary`, which is probably what it's complaining about. Instead, you can call `ToDictionary()` on the `IEnumerable` to get your `Dictionary`. Something like this...

```
    Dim query = From row In AdDr.Cast(Of Data.Common.DbDataRecord)() _
                Select New With { _
                    .Items =  _
                        (From ii In Enumerable.Range(0, row.FieldCount) _
                         Select New With { .Key =row.GetName(ii), .Value = row.GetValue(ii) } ).ToDictionary(Function (x) x.Key, Function(x) x.Value) _
                    }
```